# In Typescript what does Record<K extends keyof any, T> mean?

Tags: typescript

I came across this code -

```
type Record<K extends keyof any, T> = {
    [P in K]: T;
};
```

Here, I understand that T> is a generic type assertion.

Can someone please explain what is K?
And please explain what this function returns with a sample i/o?

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: this is actually a type definition of a key: value store. The K extends key of any is just a generic type constraint. I however have no idea what that P in K means for the key type.

Comment: Thank you bturner1273 and @yqlim. It partially answered my question.

Comment: keyof any is a subset of any, i.e. keys can only be string, number, symbol. So the type `keyof any` is `string | number | symbol`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, [`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html) returns a union of all keys of a type.

```typescript
type BadVector = { x: string, y: boolean }
keyof BadVector // "x" | "y"
```

So, `K extends keyof any` says that `K` is such a keyof union type. For example, the type `keyof BadVector` would extend `keyof any`.

Second, a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) maps all keys of an object to a new value type. So `[P in K]: T` means: Map each property `P` in `K` to a value type `T`.

For example, take the [example from the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type):

```typescript
interface CatInfo {
  age: number;
  breed: string;
}
 
type CatName = "miffy" | "boris" | "mordred";
 
const cats: Record<CatName, CatInfo> = {
  miffy: { age: 10, breed: "Persian" },
  boris: { age: 5, breed: "Maine Coon" },
  mordred: { age: 16, breed: "British Shorthair" },
};
```

The type of `cats` is `Record<CatName, CatInfo>`. This means that for all types in `CatName`, a value with the type `CatInfo` must be provided.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @linkuskmr :)